# How do I add a custom string next to the equation number?

Tags: equations, labels

I would like to add a custom string (like the name of an equation) just left of the equation number like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```latex
\newcommand{\eqnum}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag*{#1 (\theequation)}}
```

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\eqnum}[1]{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag*{#1 (\theequation)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    E = mc^2 \eqnum{Banana}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]